# How to find some data through many id?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have ID array type. ex) Long id = [1, 3, 5]
Then how to find the data use array type id?

Array data type not applicable to findById() method.
So i tried loop function.
But this style is not good to performance Because it is execute the method several times for id's length.

```
Long id = [1, 3, 5];

for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    repository.findById(id[i]);
}
```

Board Table

id    | title    | content

==============================

1    | A...     | A is...

2    | B...     | B is...

3    | C...     | C is...

4    | D...     | D is...

5    | E...     | E is...

I want same result use JPA method(NOT Native Query Style) below query.

SELECT 
    title, 
    content
FROM Board
WHERE id = 1, or id = 3, or id = 5;

Result

id    | title    | content

==============================

1    | A...     | A is...

3    | C...     | C is...

5    | E...     | E is...

Comment: The SQL you want is `SELECT title, content FROM Board WHERE id IN (1, 3, 5);`. Can you find the equivalent in Hibernate in its doco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `CrudRepository` you can use the method `findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids)` to find some data

```
String[] ids = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
Iterable<T> result = repository.findById(Arrays.asList(ids))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `findByIdIn(List<Long> ids)` .It is the Spring data JPA method to get the data.

Your method should be

`List<Board> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids)` in `BaordRepository`